# select specific records with specific ordering without using a common condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My purpose the following:

I have a list of "StudentID"... Let's say: 4, 2, 3, 5, 7 (stored in an array for example),
and I want to make a select statement that returns StudentID and StudentName of the specified studentID in the list, ***with the same order of the list***.

So the result should be:

```
StudentID StudentName
4         Philip
2         Mary
3         Tima
5         Lara
7         Michel
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What database are you using? What language are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008, C# (ADO.NET)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with a union query, you need to inject an order parameter/value to the sql tough.

```
select studentId, studentName from (
    select 1 as rowOrder, studentID, studentName from <table> where studentID = 4 UNION ALL
    select 2, studentID, studentName from <table> where studentID = 2 UNION ALL
    select 3, studentID, studentName from <table> where studentID = 3 UNION ALL
    select 4, studentID, studentName from <table> where studentID = 5 UNION ALL
    select 5, studentID, studentName from <table> where studentID = 7) as x
order by rowOrder
```

Answer (score 5):

I would get that array of IDs into a temp table and join against that temp table for the select. Creating an identity column in the temp table will preserve the desired order.

```
create table #temp (
    SortID int identity,
    StudentID int
)

insert into #temp 
    (StudentID)
    select 4 union all
    select 2 union all
    select 3 union all
    select 5 union all
    select 7

select s.StudentID, s.StudentName
    from StudentTable s
        inner join #temp t
             on s.StudentID = t.StudentID
    order by t.SortID
```

Comment: Thank you, But as I see, you used "union all", isn't it better to use the code of Rene (another answer)? so we prevent creating another table...

Comment: @yazanpro: I believe creating a second table that can be used in a `JOIN` would be more efficient than dealing with an `IN` clause, especially for a large number of StudentIDs.

Comment: One last thing: do you know which is the most efficient solution between the following 3 solutions: 1) your solution. 2) hazimdikenli's solution. 3) the following code:               select StudentID, StudentName from Students where StudentID = 4 UNION ALL
select StudentID, StudentName from Students where StudentID = 2 UNION ALL
select StudentID, StudentName from Students where StudentID = 3 UNION ALL
select StudentID, StudentName from Students where StudentID = 5 UNION ALL
select StudentID, StudentName from Students where StudentID = 7

Comment: @yazanpro: I believe my version will perform better, however I would encourage you to benchmark each solution on your own system and see for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If your database supports `case` in select statements, the following returns the queried data in the desired order:

```
select 
  StudentID, 
  StudentName 
from 
  <table>
where 
  StudentID in (4,2,3,5,7)
order by 
  case studendID 
     when 4 then 1 
     when 2 then 2
     when 3 then 3
     when 5 then 4
     when 7 then 5
   end;
```

Comment: Long winded but only answer that would produce the expected result all the time.

Comment: I agree with this solution. single row select for each id, and union of them. Alternatively you can just get the data from database and apply the sorting afterwards

Comment: Why did you omit the other solution (UNION ALL)? it worked for me... does it have a problem or is it not efficient?

Comment: It has a problem in that it doesn't guarantee that the returned records are in the order of the statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
select studentID, studentName 
from Students 
where studentID in (4, 2, 3, 5, 7)
```

Comment: Beware though, this operation is expensive and gets even worse the long the collection of "IN" variables grows.

Comment: So what would you propose instead?

Comment: My original system is a search engine, so I implemented many algorithms to find the resulted Ids and their orders, So finally I need to show them up (keeping their orders)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that splits your comma separated string/array and then used in a join to Students.

```
declare @IDs varchar(max)
set @IDs = '4,2,3,5,7'

;with cte
as
(
  select
    left(@IDs, charindex(',', @IDs)-1) as ID,
    right(@IDs, len(@IDs)-charindex(',', @IDs)) as IDs,
    1 as Sort
  union all
  select
    left(IDs, charindex(',', @IDs)-1) as ID,
    right(IDs, len(IDs)-charindex(',', IDs)) as IDs,
    Sort + 1 as Sort
  from cte
  where charindex(',', IDs) > 1
  union all
  select
    IDs as ID,
    '' as IDs,
    Sort + 1 as Sort
  from cte
  where
    charindex(',', IDs) = 0 and
    len(IDs) > 0
)
select
  cte.ID as StudentID,
  Students.StudentName
from cte
  inner join Students
    on cte.ID = Students.StudentID  
order by cte.Sort
```

BTW, there's more than one way to split a string.  A search on SO will give you a lot to pick from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select * From Employees Where Employees.ID in(1,5,2,3) 
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(','+CONVERT(varchar, Employees.ID)+',', ',1,5,2,3,')
```